# Copy the filtered dates, do Formatting and paste it back to filtered column

Tags: vba, excel

I have the dates columns in the sheet name "Dates" where the format of the dates are wrong. I filter the wrong dates to sheet name "Raw Dates" where I have placed formulas that corrects the date format in (col I) and when I'm trying to paste the dates back to same column I am getting debug.

Not sure which is correct VBA code, below is code and also attaching the excel file for your reference.

If you have a better option than this, then would be appreciated.

```
Sub DateFormat()

Dt = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1), "YYYY")
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
        xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "12/9/" & Dt)
    Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Sheets("Raw Dates").Range("A2")

Sheets("Raw Dates").Select
Lrw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("B2:I" & Lrw).FillDown
Range("I2:I" & Lrw).Copy

Sheets("Dates").Select
Range("A2:A" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'stuck here

End Sub
```

Regards,
Rajkumar H

Comment: Try shortening your question to what specifically the issue is, and only show the code that reproduces your issue. In this case, what is causing the bad formatting. Other details of what you've tried and environment would be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just apply your formula directly to the visible cells in column A, after you have filtered?

```
Dt = Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 1), "YYYY")
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=1, Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(0, "12/9/" & Dt)
For Each c In Sheets("Dates").Range("A2:A" & lr)
       If c.Visible = True Then
         'apply your formula to the cell value
        End If
    next c
```